# Что за конструкция Class Foo:Bar,new(){ public Foo(){}}

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Разбираюсь в исходниках Asp.Net встретил следущую конструкцию

```
public class OAuthMiddleware<TOptions> : AuthenticationMiddleware<TOptions>               
   where TOptions : OAuthOptions, new()
{
    public OAuthMiddleware()
    { 
        //code here...
    }     
}
```

Класс `OAuthMiddleware` наследует класс `AuthenticationMiddleware` и `new()`
Возникло три вопроса.

1. `new()` - это анонимный класс?
2. Почему в этом анонимном классе конструктор `OAuthMiddleware`
3. Для чего используется подобная конструкция? Какой это шаблон проектирование, если известно, что от этого класса наследуются другие?

Comment: [Generic constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваш тип `OAuthMiddleware` — это обобщённый тип (generic) с параметром `TOptions`, и то, что после `where` — это *ограничения* на этот самый тип-параметр вашего обобщённого типа.

```
where TOptions : OAuthOptions, new()
```

означает, что тип `TOptions` должен

- быть наследником `OAuthOptions`, и
- иметь публичный конструктор без параметров.

Для чего может понадобиться ограничение `new()`? Например, в коде класса можно будет *создать* экземпляр этого типа:

```
TOptions opt = new TOptions();
```

Без ограничения на существование такого конструктора этот код невозможно было бы скомпилировать.

Comment: ясно типа(класса) TOption изначально не существует, это не зарезервированное слово. Создаётся класс TOption наследуя от анонимного класса и класса OAuthOptions?

Comment: @MaratBatalandabad: Не, он не создаётся, он _указывается_. Вы не можете написать просто `OAuthMiddleware`, вы обязаны всегда указать параметр, например: `OAuthMiddleware<OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>`. При этом нужно, чтобы тип `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` (1) Существовал, (2) Наследовался от `OAuthOptions`, и (3) Имел конструктор без параметров. Анонимных классов тут вообще нигде нет.